# How to type cast in F#?

Tags: types, f#, casting

I have to enumerate through the members of a collection and create an array with a particular property of the members:

```
  let ops: int array = [| for x in app.Operations ->
                            let op=  x : IAzOperation
                            op.OperationID |]
```

Here `app.Operations` is a collection of IAzOperation but on enumeration, returns each member as `Obj`. So I want to type cast each member and access the property. but not sure how to typecast it.
If I typecast the way I've mentioned here, it gives me error that:

```
This espression was expected to have type IAzOPeration but here has type obj.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need the downcasting operator `:?>`:

```
let ops: int array = [| for x in app.Operations do
                          let op =  x :?> IAzOperation
                          yield op.OperationID |]
```

As the symbol `?` in its name denotes, downcasting could fail and result in a runtime exception.

In case of sequences, you have another option to use [Seq.cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370344.aspx):

```
let ops: int array = 
    [| for op in app.Operations |> Seq.cast<IAzOperation> -> op.OperationID |]
```

Comment: For completeness, version with pattern matching [| for :? IAzOperation as op in app.Operations -> op.OperationID |]

Answer (score 11):

```
type Base1() =
    abstract member F : unit -> unit
    default u.F() =
     printfn "F Base1"

type Derived1() =
    inherit Base1()
    override u.F() =
      printfn "F Derived1"


let d1 : Derived1 = Derived1()

// Upcast to Base1.
let base1 = d1 :> Base1

// This might throw an exception, unless
// you are sure that base1 is really a Derived1 object, as
// is the case here.
let derived1 = base1 :?> Derived1

// If you cannot be sure that b1 is a Derived1 object,
// use a type test, as follows:
let downcastBase1 (b1 : Base1) =
   match b1 with
   | :? Derived1 as derived1 -> derived1.F()
   | _ -> ()

downcastBase1 base1
```